# Server socket close the connection in SendCallback

Tags: java, c#, android, .net, sockets

I create a `windows form` that is server socket and `android app` that is client socket. For server socket I follow [this tutorial from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx). My problem is when I call send from server, socket will be close and I can't received message from user anymore. When I delete `ShotDown` and `Close` socket from `SendCallback` method, nothing sent to client till I stop the server and message will be send to the client. Here is `SendCallback` method:

```
private  void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);

    // When I delete this two lines, nothing send to client
    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    handler.Close();
}
```

I can't understands why these line must be in `SendCallback`.

Comment: These lines do not have to be in the send handler. They are supposed to be called when you are completely done with the socket. Your sends will be received eventually, maybe with a 200ms nagling delay. Maybe your receiving code is broken?

Comment: @usr I use wireShark for monitoring network and when I delete those lines, nothing send through the selected port. I'm sure my client codes works fine.

Comment: Maybe you issued zero lengths sends? Those would not appear on the wire. Besides that there is nothing that could cause this. One of your assumptions is wrong. Bad Wireshark trace, bug in code, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to my question:** Server socket put the data into buffer (That's what WireShark says) but android client can't read the data. I figure it out this is because I use `in.readLine()` in my java client to read data from socket but it only works when send data has end line at the end of that, So I just add `\n` at the end of any message from server and every things are OK now.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the remarks section of the msdn ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.shutdown(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)). Closing the handler forces a flush to take place and send whatever is still remaining in the socket.

> When using a connection-oriented Socket, always call the Shutdown method before closing the Socket. This ensures that all data is **sent and received on the connected socket before it is closed**.

With the design implemented on the msdn article, it requires the close. A google search will show you different implementations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's says we must use Shutdown before closing the socket, but I don't want to close the socket in send method. I don't think this was the problem

Comment: With TCP there is no way to "flush" the socket. The only way to 100% force it is by closing the socket. So if your server implementation is holding the data and not releasing it, or is blocked, the client won't receive anything. You can disable nagle but it's not advised. It is more likely to be your implementation (either client or server) that is causing issues. More than the connection itself. Non-blocking sockets are a way you can go. Googling that could help you. 

I'm curious however - Why do you need a constant stream? Whats wrong with calling, sending, recieve and hang up?

Comment: Also, your socket type being known would help a lot.